# When is jen- used?

Tags: word-usage, pronoun

I've learned that `dies-` can mean `this` or `that`, whereas `jen-` can also mean that.

When should `jen-` be used in preference to `dies-`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The demonstrative pronouns *dieser/diese/diese* and *jener/jene/jenes* are used as demonstrative articles, as stand alone words or as a substitute for a noun.

`dies-` refers to something that is spatially or temporally **closer**.

`jene-` points to something that is spatially or temporally **distant**.

Examples:

> Dieser Baum, vor dem ich stehe, ist sehr hoch.
>
> Das Restaurant in diesem Ort ist besser als jenes in Berlin.
>
> Ich bevorzuge dieses Essen gegenüber jenem von gestern.
>
> Diese Frau, mit der ich gerade telefoniert habe, ruft jeden Tag an.
>
> Ich hatte jene Frau, die wir gestern getroffen haben, vorher nicht gekannt.

There are also some derived adverbs:

- diesseits: on this side
- jenseits: on the other side

The noun *das Diesseits* means our world/life, while *das Jenseits* means "afterlife."

Comment: I also find it worth noting that "jene/-r/-s" sounds rather formal and is rarely used in spoken German. This is not the case with "jenseits".

Comment: +1 to splattne for the concise answer and to elena for the addition. "Jene/-r/-s" are now so rarely used that in many cases its presence can in some cases serve as an indicator that a text is a translation, where the translator sticks too close to the source. (Incidentally, the same is true for "welche/-r/-s", where "der/die/das" is much more common.)

Comment: @Mac, @elena, whether `jen-` is no longer used in spoken German was actually one of the important points of my question (which I unfortunately failed to emphasize).  Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: @Matt It's universally understood and still used in more formal circumstances (even in spoken language), maybe kind of like the correct subjunctive in english (I wish I *were* rich). It all depends on the setting and company you're in. Use (usage?) in written language is no problem at all.

Comment: @fzwo -- I'd be excited if you could expand on that in an answer!

Comment: @Matt I don't really have enough meaningful information to add that isn't already in splattne's excellent answer to merit a whole new answer. But I'll be glad to answer questions in the comments, if you have any.

Comment: Note that I *relatively often* hear *jene* in colloquial language, both at work and at home. It's not as often as *dieses*, of course, but because of this, I wouldn't actually say *rarely used in spoken German*. Rarely used is a word like *fürderhin*, and I even used that one when writing to one of our customers from Austria...

Comment: if `jene-` points to something that is spatially or temporally distant, why not simply translate it as `that`?

Comment: Ist die zeitliche Entfernung nicht nur eine Korrelation? Geht es bei diesem vs. jenem nicht um die Stellung Satz? "Ich bevorzuge das Essen von gestern gegenüber jenem von heute."